A crystal on $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S)$ is the same as giving a projective system of crystals on $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S_n)$ with compatability?
I'm currently reading Berthelot- Cohomologie cristalline des schémas de caractéristique p>0 and I'm having a question on page 228.
He claims that if $X=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ for a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p$ and $S=\operatorname{Spec}(W(k))$ the spectrum of Witt vectors as well as $S_n=\operatorname{Spec}(W_n(k))$, then giving a crystal on $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S)$ is the same as having a projective system of quasi-coherent $M_n$ on $X$ such that $M_n\otimes_{W_n}W_{n-1}$ is isomorphic to $M_{n-1}$.
My question is how to see that this is true. My idea was to define for every object $(U, T,\delta)$ of $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S)$ a quasi-coherent sheaf and then see that this fulfils the necessary compatibilities.
I'm unsure if my idea makes any sense, but I tried to do it in the following way: Assume $T$ is quasi-compact. Then, since $p$ is locally nilpotent on $T$, the PD-morphism $T\to S$ factors over $S_n$ for some $n$, and then we have a morphism in $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S_n)$ from $T$ to the final object $X$ in $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S_n)$. We can pull back $M_n$ to $T$, giving us the quasi-coherent sheaf.
However, I don't know how to do this without the assumption that $T$ is quasi-compact and if my idea makes any sense. It would be nice to know if an object $(U, T,\delta)$ in $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S)$ can be viewed as an object in $\operatorname{Cris}(X/S_n)$ for some $n$.
I appreciate your help.
